# Escape sequences vs predefined character classes (aka special regex characters) when encapsulated by double quotes

Tags: java, python, regex, perl

Perl, like Java and Python, has `\s`, the special regex character that matches whitespace, in addition to other special characters.

In Perl, the following would not be valid:

```perl
my $sentence = "The End";
my $subStr = "\s"; #Does NOT work, needs to be "\\s" or '\s'

if ($sentence =~ /$subStr/)
{
    say "True";
}
```

In Java, this would be valid:

```java
String s = "The End";

if (s.matches(".*\\s.*")) //same deal as with Perl ("\\s")
{
    System.out.println("True");
}
```

In Python, one could use either `"\s"` or `'\s'`.

Both Java and Perl seem to treat special regex characters encapsulated by `""` the same. I looked up [Predefined Character Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)(Java), and it simply said: *"If you are using an escaped construct within a string literal, you must precede the backslash with another backslash for the string to compile."*

Why do both Java and Perl treat escape sequences differently than special regex characters (when they're both encapsulated by `""`), yet, python doesn't?

As in why did the designers make the choice for escape sequences, like `\n` or `\t`, to require one backslash, but for predefined character classes, like `\s`, to require two (while in `""`)?

Is this a consequence of something else? Or does it in some way simplify some sort of interaction(s) or what have you?

I'm going to assume that it wasn't arbitrary.  Python only requires `\` either way, yet Perl and Java mandate `\\` when dealing with `""`.  Besides being a little confusing, it's just messy.  So, I assume that there's a good reason for this decision.  Anyone know why?

Comment: In Python, you can make the string a raw string: `r'\s\r\n'`.

Comment: Note that in Java, you can do `if (Pattern.compile("\\s").find())` -- yeah, `.matches()` is misnamed

Comment: I don't know the exact reason but I'd say C/Unix is no stranger to that decision... The `\\` has always been the escape character for strings in C and for the shell! (even on SO it is, I had to double it to include it in the single quotes)

Comment: Perl has many different quote operators - you would likely not write `"\\s"` in practice, but rather `'\s'` or `q(\s)`, etc.

Comment: @jwd, `'\s'` is just as unlikely as `"\\s"`. One would use the quote-regex operator: `qr/\s/`

Comment: @ikegami: I was assuming he wanted to build the regex dynamically from strings, as written in the question. But yes, if you want a real regex object, `qr//` is better.

Comment: @jwd, So was I. You can easily interpolate the result of qr in a string or regex.

Comment: All of these comments together make up a great answer to why you should use the right tools (raw strings, pattern literals, etc.)—if you do the right thing, this question doesn't even come up. I should have just referred to them instead of trying to explain it in my answer

Comment: @ikegami: Ah, good point. But just to be clear for readers, the two methods result in different things, as `print qr/\s/` yields `(?^:\s)` rather than a plain `\s`. The `qr//` result is actually a different fundamental type than a string (though it's usually auto-converted). Depends on what you really want, as always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java, Perl, and Python all use C-style backslashes for escapes. Regex also uses C-style backslashes for escapes. This leads to problems in all three languages—and, in fact, for many, many other languages.

For example, all three languages will convert `'\\'` into a single backslash, `'\n'` into a newline, etc., before they can get to the regex compiler.

The only difference is that in Python, unknown escape sequences like `'\s'` resolve to themselves, while in Java and Perl they resolve to just `'s'`. So, in Python, while you need `'\\\n'`, you don't need `'\\s'`, while in Java and Perl, you need to escape the backslashes for both.

And there are languages that make the third choice, treating unknown escape sequences as errors.

---

So, if you have the list of known escapes memorized, you can sometimes get away with not escaping backslashes in Python. But you really shouldn't.

Why not? Because, even if you're absolutely sure you've memorized the escape sequences, do you really want to make that a requirement for anyone who wants to read (or maintain) your code? When I see `"abc\\sdef"` or `r"abc\sdef"`, I immediately know exactly what it means. When I see unescaped `"abc\sdef"`, I *think* I know, but I may be wrong, and I have to go look it up or try it in the interpreter to find out.

---

The right thing to do is to escape your backslashes, or use the appropriate raw-string or regex-literal syntax for your language.

---

If you're wondering why Python made a different design choice for unknown escapes from Perl and Java… As far as I know, that's not covered in the official [Design FAQ](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html) and hasn't been directly addressed by Guido. But I can guess. In general, Perl went with maximal compatibility with C (and Java with C++) as a high priority in many areas, where Python put more priority on what made more intuitive sense to a programming teacher. This is probably one of those areas. (I suspect if Python were re-designed from scratch today, or even way back when raw strings were added, it would go with the error.)

Comment: "But you really shouldn't."  Why not?